# Is there a way to run a script every time `sudo` is run?

Tags: sudo

I'm using Arch Linux. This is mainly for installing things with `yay`, as well as wanting to be notified of `sudo` calls for security monitoring.

An annoying but common problem with `yay` is that it often needs to call `sudo` somewhere in the process of installing packages but we usually don't know when, and missing that password prompt can mean having to rerun a bunch of things for the package, and I can't rely on myself to check on it every 5 minutes because I forget. I want a notification every time `yay` needs `sudo` so I can enter my password and let it continue.

I also want to be notified of calls to `sudo` so that I can better see (and maybe log) every time `sudo` is called without me explicitly running it myself. It would also be great if every `sudo` is logged somewhere so I can backtrack if something goes wrong.

Is there a way to get `sudo` to execute a script every time it's called?

Comment: You could write a wrapper-script named ```sudo``` and alter the ```PATH``` variable so the script is found before the real sudo. E.g. ```export PATH="/path/to/my/sudo:$PATH"```

Comment: Adjust this to your needs: [*How to have `sudo` show the command in the password prompt?*](https://superuser.com/q/1721429/432690)

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question literally: yes, there is such a way, by virtue of *sudo*'s (the *sudoers* plugin, more exactly) integration with PAM. Simply add a line that calls [*pam_exec.so*](https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/linux-pam/1.1.2/reference/sag-pam_exec.html) in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, at the appropriate location(s) in the PAM stack for the purpose of your script.

Looking at the broader context of your question, however, scripting may not be necessary. Another approach could be to run *yay* as a dedicated non-login sudoer and configure *sudo* to allow that user to run commands without a password. This would also answer the log question as it would then be possible to inspect *sudo*'s log and filter on user *yay*.

**CAUTION!!!** If your *root* account is disabled, the use of *visudo* is strongly advised when editing *sudo*'s configuration.

If the *yay* package doesn't already create a dedicated user upon installation, you can create one manually with:

```
# useradd --system --home /tmp --shell /bin/nologin yay
```

The following line added to `/etc/sudoers` (or one of `/etc/sudoers.d/*`) will allow the *yay* user to run any command without a password:

```
yay ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If you can narrow down the needs of *yay* to a fixed set of commands, the following form will allow only those commands without a password (if the list is long, you can define a command alias with *Cmnd_Alias*):

```
yay ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/something, /sbin/another, ...
```

Then, you can launch *yay* like this. You will still need to enter your password once at first, but *yay* won't:

```
$ sudo -u yay yay
```

Comment: This is a solution. But keep in mind that this runs **everything ```yay/commandX``` does** with root privileges (-- instead of only running the parts that need root privileges with root privileges).

Comment: That is not correct. The *yay* user is not the *root* user; it runs with normal user privilege. Only when it calls a command with *sudo* (without the ```-u``` switch) does it acquire *root* privilege.

Comment: When the yay user runs a command you defined as requiring no sudo password in the sudoers file, all parts of this command/program are run with full root privileges opposed to only the parts the command/program requests via sudo.

Comment: That is incorrect again. Try it and you shall see that ```$ sudo -u yay ls /root``` results in ```ls: cannot open directory '/root': Permission denied``` while ```$ sudo -u yay sudo ls /root``` results in the listing of the ```/root``` folder.

Comment: I stand corrected. I won't delete my wrong comments for educational purposes.

Comment: It was nonetheless a relevant concern. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: You are too kind.

Answer (score 2):

In view of the PAM integration suggested by mesr, an alternative I see would be to configure your sudo to log via syslog using a unique identifier and have your system's rsyslog/syslog-ng invoke an external program/script for these messages.  Or perhaps just log to a file that's different from the traditional logfiles in /var.

I don't have an example at hand, but I can work one out if you need.